# Unexpected result combining WHERE and WITH with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am a beginner with Neo4j and I think that I did not properly understand how WITH and WHERE work.

I have a graph and I would like to count the number of nodes that I obtain if I exclude all the nodes with a certain label and I exclude all the nodes that have a degree > 20.

I first tried to this in a simple way, writing multiple queries for removing the nodes like:

```
MATCH(n:label1) DETACH DELETE n

MATCH(n:label2) DETACH DELETE n
```

and then

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, size((n)-[]-()) as degree
WHERE degree>20
DETACH DELETE n
```

Then I counted the number of the nodes that I have in the graph with

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN count(n)
```

and I obtained 892

I generate again the original graph from scratch and I tried to combine all the previous queries in a single one:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT n:label1
AND NOT n:label2
WITH n, size((n)-[]-()) as degree
WHERE degree>20
DETACH DELETE n
```

If I count the number of nodes I obtained 713.

Why is the result different?

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The following explanation is speculation, since you have not provided sample data. But it does conform to what you have presented.

In your first trial, you first deleted all `label1` and `label2` nodes (and all their relationships), and that apparently reduced the degree-ness of some of the remaining nodes to below 21. Therefore, when you deleted the >20 degree nodes, there were fewer such nodes (as compared to your second trial), and you ended up with 892 remaining nodes.

In your second trial, all the nodes *without* those 2 labels still had their connections to nodes *with* those 2 labels, and so you had more >20 degree nodes to delete. That is why you ended up with 713 remaining nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your combined query isn't doing the same thing as your previous queries. Specifically, you aren't deleting nodes with the labels `label1` and `label2`, you're excluding them from your query, which means they won't be deleted (even if they have degree > 20).

The two delete operations are working on entirely different sets of nodes, so it won't make sense to bring across `n` in your WITH. Instead, use a WITH to [reset your result cardinality to 1](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/resetting-query-cardinality/) (through usage of DISTINCT or an aggregation), then match on the other nodes you want to delete and take care of them.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:label1
OR n:label2
DETACH DELETE n
WITH count(n) as deleted
MATCH (n)
WHERE size((n)-[]-()) > 20
DETACH DELETE n
```